# What is the Django setup for session?

Tags: django

I want to save sessions in server side instead of db. right now my project using db to store sessions, as per documentation i removed `'django.contrib.sessions'` from installed app but its giving error `RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sessions.models.Session doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.` . So, what is the actual setup for session?

--my settings--

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = '#########################################'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myuser',

]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'signup.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'signup.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}




AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'allstaticfiles')
```

Comment: What documentation did you follow?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-file-based-sessions

Comment: Chidananda Nayak Can you show your settings.py.....Because when you get this error it is because you forget to declare you app in settings.py correctly

Comment: @rakwen I have updated it,please have a look.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it says `If you want to use a database-backed session, you need to add 'django.contrib.sessions' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.` so i commented it out....

Comment: No no you have market out session (#'django.contrib.sessions',) remove # and try again it work...

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: I think you make a logical mistake here: modus tollens says "if p then q, implies not q then not p", not "not p then not q".

Comment: @rakwen: this is the idea since the aim is a non-persistent (non-database) implementation of sessions.

Comment: Read this my brother ....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions  -------You have all you want ....

Comment: If you don’t want to use sessions, you might as well remove the SessionMiddleware line from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and 'django.contrib.sessions' from your INSTALLED_APPS. It’ll save you a small bit of overhead.

Comment: @rakwen Thanks a lot mate, no,i want to use session.

Comment: Ok read first my link....

Comment: @rakwen: he wants to use sessions, but store the sessions in memory so not in a database. That is - based on my understanding - the scope of the question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem YES YES 100% CORRECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the shared settings file, you forgot to specify the `SESSION_ENGINE`:

> **Set `SESSION_ENGINE` to `"django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"`** for a simple caching session store. Session data will be stored directly in your cache. However, session data may not be persistent: cached data can be evicted if the cache fills up or if the cache server is restarted.

So you should add the following to the `settings.py` file:

```
# settings.py

# ...

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

Comment: so i can use request.session for this to store session_id! 
i use request.session.create() to create session, request.session.delete() to delete and request.session.session_key to know the existing key.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: noo!!! this would be a huge anti-pattern, and probably violate ten design principles. Use middleware to handle the session.

Comment: I mean i use these in views.py to create session. So now i have to use SESSION_ENGINE means those `request.session` requests would work or not?

Comment: Yes, normally it should work? Are there still errors? You need to restart the server, since settings are - iirc - only loaded in the beginning.

Comment: so i need to run migrate after inserting engine code?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: no normally there are no migrations, since this has no impact on the database at all.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! YOU SAVED ME SIR

Comment: can I use in a site which would be used by millions?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: the size is not the problem. But there are other challenges about serving that many users like scalability, etc. If you do load balancing, then it is possible that caching sessions is not an option (depending on how the load balancer works) since the user might each time trigger a view on different machines.

Comment: then sir which server side engine should I use?

Comment: Well this is typically the reason why one uses databases: there are then several servers that work with replication, and caching. But as said, it is a very challenging problem, and all large websites have a hard time with this. It is not much the backend itself that is the inherent problem, more how one can synchronize. Other attempts are MPIs, en tuple-space (object-space), but these all are not very elegantly.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: that depends how you organize the load balancing. Like said before the challenge is if multiple servers are involved, how to communicate changes from one server to another and vice versa. By saving a file on a server, this syncing is *not* guaranteed. So then it requires some extra "infrastructure" to perform this task.

Comment: yeah sir, thats why i think i can use file? it would be a problem?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: it *could* be a problem, but that all depends in what "context" the system is embedded.